# Trouble installing discord overlay and pyQt5

Tags: software-installation, pip

I get this error

```
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt5 (from discordoverlaylinux==0.0.1) (from versions: )
```

No matching distribution found for PyQt5 (from discordoverlaylinux==0.0.1)

when trying to install [discord overlay](https://github.com/trigg/DiscordOverlayLinux)

I tried fixing this by manually installing pyQt5 by `pip install pyqt5` but i get

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt5 (from versions: )
```

No matching distribution found for PyQt5

what should i do to fix this?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to install the packages from official repository by

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5.qtwebengine pyqt5-dev python3-xdg
```